# Will Priorities affect other programs on the same computer?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a code as this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            //extremely time-consuming actions
        }
    });
thread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
thread.start();
```

The thread will do some time-consuming action and it also has high-priority.

Now I want to know will this thread has higher priority **among all other programs of my system** or it just have higher priority in comparison of the **threads of same program**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The priority is within threads in the process and not across processes. The JVM may even [choose to ignore the priority](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/thread-priorities.html#javabackground), so you are not even guaranteed priority within the process itself.

> The JVM defines a range of ten logical priorities for Java threads,
>   including:
>
> java.lang.Thread.MIN_PRIORITY  = 1
>
> java.lang.Thread.NORM_PRIORITY = 5
>
> java.lang.Thread.MAX_PRIORITY  = 10
>
> These values [1..10] are passed into Thread.setPriority(int) to assign
>   priorities to Java threads. The default priority of a Java thread is
>   NORM_PRIORITY. (A Java thread that doesn't explicitly call setPriority
>   runs at NORM_PRIORITY.) A JVM is free to implement priorities in any
>   way it chooses, **including ignoring the value**.

Answer (score 1):

Only of the same program - in the VM itself. But this is also not a guarantee, just a hint for the VM.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to generalize as it depends on the underlying platform. Java Thread priority gets mapped to OS thread priorities and usually there is no one-to-one mapping.  Some of the platforms provide priority level from 1 to 10. But Java provides only 3 levels.

So it's OS responsiblity to treat all threads with same priority from applications as well as its own threads equally and fairly.